# How could I put my private int into the public int

Tags: java, private, public

I want scramble an array by using Math.random multiple times but I don't know how to put the random int into scramble and use the random int multiple times.

```
 public static void scramble(int[] array){ 
  for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length - 1; i++){
     int temp = array[i];
     array[i] = array[random];
     array[random] = temp;}}

public int random (){
  return (int)(Math.random() *9) + 1;}
```

Output

```
100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 //Default
 101 104 102 105 103 106 108 109 100 107 //Scrambled
  100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109//Then sorted
```

Whole Driver

```
    import java.lang.Math;

public class Driver03{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      int[] array = {100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109};
      print(array);
      scramble(array);
      print(array);

      print(array);}

   public static void print(int[] array){
      for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
         System.out.print(" " + array[x]);}
      System.out.println("");}

   public static void scramble(int[] array){ 
      int random = random();
      for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length - 1; i++){
         int temp = array[i];
         array[i] = array[random];
         array[random] = temp;}}

   public int random (){
      return (int)(Math.random() *9) + 1;}

}
```

Comment: Could you explain better? It would also be useful to have an example of your input and your expected output

Comment: One thing to be careful of is your random() function is returning a value between 1 and 9, if the array passed into the scramble() function isn't at least 10 elements long, you may receive index out of range exceptions. You may want to update the random() function to accept an argument for the number of elements in the array to be scrambled.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to call the random function like that "random()" not just random

try this code:

```
public static void scramble(int[] array){ 
  int random = random();
  for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length - 1; i++){
     int temp = array[i];
     array[i] = array[random];
     array[random] = temp;}}

public static int random (){
 return (int)(Math.random() *9) + 1;}
```

Comment: I did try this but this error came up "non-static method random() cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Add "static" to "random":

Comment: @ChaseDiaz , I updated the code. I think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using the [Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm).

```
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    int[] values = new int[] { 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109 };
    System.out.println( "Start: " + Arrays.toString( values ) );
    scramble( values );
    System.out.println( "Scrambled: " + Arrays.toString( values ) );
    Arrays.sort( values );
    System.out.println( "Sorted: " + Arrays.toString( values ) );
  }

  public static void scramble( int[] array )
  {
    // Scramble using the Fisher-Yates shuffle.
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for ( int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++ )
    {
      int random = i + rnd.nextInt( array.length - 1 - i );
      int temp = array[ random ];
      array[ random ] = array[ i ];
      array[ i ] = temp;
    }
  }
```

It doesn't use `Math.random()` but an instance of `Random` instead.